# build svn clang with stdlibc++ 4.7

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am new to compile clang directly from svn. I want to build clang against stdlibc++4.7.

My system is running Mac OS mountain lion 10.8, so I used MacPorts to install gcc47. Now the library is in /opt/local/lib/gcc47 and headers are in /opt/local/include/gcc47.

I downloaded clang from svn and followed the guide from: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

how do i specify clang configure to use stdlibc++ 4.7? It mentions in the guide that i should specify it using `--with-gcc-toolchain`. What exactly should I use with `--with-gcc-toolchain`? is it just `../configure --with-gcc-toolchain`

I also tried to compile gcc from svn and install it into my home directory as `$HOME/gcc`. And then pass configure with `--with-gcc-toolchain=PATH_TO_GCC_IN_HOME_DIR`. After compilation, and tried the following:
`./clang -v -x c++ /dev/null -fsyntax-only`

it still shows linked with gcc4.2 lib that came with Mac OS:

```
clang version 3.2 (trunk 161295)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
Thread model: posix
"/Users/chen/Repository/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -fsyntax-only -disable-free -main-file-name null -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 128.2 -v -resource-dir /Users/chen/Repository/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/../lib/clang/3.2 -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/1l/m5km38_d3lxbrvysgv6s42680000gn/T/clang-module-cache -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/chen/Repository/build/Debug+Asserts/bin -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 145 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -x c++ /dev/null
clang -cc1 version 3.2 based upon LLVM 3.2svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/i686-apple-darwin8/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/backward"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
/usr/local/include
/Users/chen/Repository/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/../lib/clang/3.2/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

How can I compile clang with libstdc++ 4.7?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just build clang with the system compiler?  Is there a reason you want to link against a different C++ library?

Comment: C++11 is not supported with libstdc++ 4.2. And I want to avoid the libc++ for now.

Comment: Does clang or llvm use C++11 features?  I'm surprised.

Comment: building clang doesn't require c++11 features. but I want to use clang to compile other program in C++11 mode. Which is not supported using default clang unless use libc++. But some programs conforms/compiles against libstdc++ not libc++.

Comment: Oh ok - I get it now.  So do you really need to do anything about that at clang build time?  Can't you just link against whatever library you want later?

Comment: yeah, from whatever i read so far it requires rebuilding clang. http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-April/021053.html

Comment: I am able to build the whole thing now and recorded here:
http://chinux23.github.com/blog/2012/08/06/build-clang-with-stdlibc-plus-plus-4-dot-7/

Comment: if anyone has better solution, I am willing to accept it

Comment: Ideally, `--with-gcc-toolchain=/opt/local` should be enough with gcc47 coming from MacPorts. In fact, I'm experiencing the same problem as OP. Still no other way other than manually editing `InitHeaderSearch.cpp`?